# Unexpected token ILLEGAL in reactjs - jest eventhough component renders correctly

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, esprima

I was trying to do unit testing for a react component. But when I tried to render it using `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument()` method jest throws an error

```
Error: Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at constructError (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2406:21)
    at createError (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2425:17)
    at unexpectedTokenError (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2500:13)
    at throwUnexpectedToken (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2504:15)
    at scanPunctuator (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:842:13)
    at advance (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1621:16)
    at lex (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1690:78)
    at expect (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2520:21)
    at parseFunctionSourceElements (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:4827:9)
    at parseFunctionExpression (node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:5073:16)
```

Poiting to nowhere inmy code. So I tried removing elements one by one and figured that the image component might be causing the probelm.

```
 <span><input type="image" title="cc" src={require('../../assets/images/cc.png') }></input></span>
```

saw an almost similer issue happened in react-native in [this post](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/919).
If anybody can show some light on it. It will be great.!

Thanks

Comment: Do you use something like wepback? If no, seems like src expects string, but require returns file content, and you get this ILLEGAL stuff.

Comment: @SergeyShvager got it working  apologies for late update.. it was require I just removed the require around the image path . and it works now .. thanks for your time